# Get a single value of an Object Array by Index

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration

I am missing something obvious here, and I think I need a new perspective.

I am passing a parameter of type object[].  I want to extract the element within the array and assign its value to another variable, as I'm looping through another list:

```
private void PopulateValues(List<SqlParameters> parameters, object[] parameterValues) {
   int index = 0;
   foreach(var parameter in parameters) {
      parameter.Value = parameterValues[index];
      index++;
   }
```

Try as I might, the parameter.Value is set to the object array rather than the object's value at position i.

What am I missing here?  Is there a different way to get at the object value inside an object array other than by index/position?

Okay .. here's exactly what I'm doing.

```
protected SqlCommand CreateStoredProcedureCommand(string storedProcedureName, object[] parameterValues)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, Connection)
                             {CommandTimeout = _commandTimeout, CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};

        SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
        int index = 0;

        foreach(SqlParameter parameter in cmd.Parameters)
        {
            if (parameter.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input || parameter.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
            {
                parameter.Value = parameterValues[index]
                index++;
            }
        }

        return cmd;
    }
```

It seems like this *should* work, so I think I'll go back and investigate what I'm actually passing.  Maybe I'm passing an array of arrays or doing something else weird.

Comment: This *does* set the parameter value to element `index` of `parameterValues`. Can you show how you're calling this method?

Comment: Something isn't right here. Are you absolutely sure that it is passing the entire array?

Comment: Are you passing an array of arrays by accident?

Comment: @duckus are you saying that `parameter.Value = parameterValues[index];` is assigning `parameter.Value = parameterValues`? What?

Comment: agree with @LeeGun. Is there a reason you are passing an object[] instead of an actual typed array?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  I was doing something weird.

I was sending the parameterValues as a list this way:

```
CreateStoredProcedureCommand("spName", pContext.SqlParameters.Select(b=>b.Value).ToList())
```

Changed it to ToArray() and it worked.

Comment: What you had shouldn't even compile unless you've used the `params` keyword in `CreateStoredProcedureCommand`, but I'm not seeing that in the code you've included in the question. That said, your solution seems correct.